Blazor Server App - Update Component when network stream is updated
Env > Blazor Server App.
I am looking for some assistance and guidance. we have a moxa device that send data over IP.I am able to get the data using the tcpipclient in my index page and update the html component with the values on the initialized sync with the current value. since the moxa device sends the data continuously, i want to update the component(textfield with a bind value) in my program continuously without clicking a button.
is there a way to implement this?
I tried using signalR by creating a HUb and trying to update the value through it but was not able to do it
